# Reading and parsing a block of data from Python3 command prompt

Tags: python-3.6

I would like to read a block of data entered from the user interactively in the Python command prompt in Windows. The data is entered all at once i.e. in one shot. Data that I want to read and parse is given below. I would like to read each line, parse it and display the output as Timezone, Time, Date

TOD Output: 2018-02-22 13:37:27 PST

TOD Output: 2018-02-22 13:37:28 PST

TOD Output: 2018-02-22 13:37:29 PST

TOD Output: 2018-02-22 13:37:30 PST

TOD Output: 2018-02-22 13:37:31 PST

TOD Output: 2018-02-22 13:37:32 PST

The code that I have written so far is below:

```
import sys

sys.stdin = input("Enter the GNSS message")
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    GNSS_data = line.split(" ")
    print("Timezone: {}".format(GNSS_data[-1]))
    print("Time: {}".format(GNSS_data[-2]))
    print("Date = {}".format(GNSS_data[-3]))
    print("\n")
```

I then get the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Tareq-Laptop/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/Decipher.py", line 4, in 
    for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'

I think I am very close to the answer but making a syntax mistake somewhere. Please tell me what is it that I am doing incorrectly.

Are there any other simple methods of accomplishing my task.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
while True:
    line = input('Enter the GNSS message')
    print(line)
    if line == 'done':
        break   
    GNSS_data = line.split(" ")
    print("Timezone: {}".format(GNSS_data[-1]))
    print("Time: {}".format(GNSS_data[-2]))
    print("Date = {}".format(GNSS_data[-3]))
    print("\n")
```

Comment: Your code works when one line of TOD Output is entered at a time. What I am trying to do is to give multiple number of such lines in one go. I want to read the block input, loop through the block to read each line and parse each one of them individually and display the output. What are the other ways in which this can be accomplished.